# Removal of automatically added extension in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

When I type: `domain.com/contact`

The page automatically displays: `domain.com/contact.php`

I want that when a user types in `domain.com/contact` the URL stays that way and displays the `contact.php` file. Is it possible?

I tried to add an `Options -Multiviews` line to the htaccess file, but then when I type `contact` the page displays a 404 error.

Moreover, I want it only for `php extension`. Because when user types domain.com/robots I don't want robots.txt to be displayed, but 404 page.

EDIT: My current .htaccess file is nothing special, here it is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /404
ErrorDocument 404 /404
```

Comment: Can you show your current .htaccess in question. Also try to test this using a new browser to avoid old browser cache.

Comment: There is no standard component in an apache http server that "automatically adds file name extensions" and redirects to a modified URL. The `MultiViews` feature would only internally rewrite, but not redirect such requests. So I assume it is your application logic that actually performs the redirection.

Comment: Did you test from a new browser?

Comment: I tested in a different browser

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is evident that your extensionless URLs are currently dependent on `MultiViews` (mod_negotiation). However, it's not clear where the external redirect (that appends the `.php` extension to the URL you are seeing in the address bar) is coming from. `MultiViews` does not do this. So, either you have some other application logic that redirects to append the extension or you are seeing a cached response from an earlier (erroneous) redirect (although if disabling `MultiViews` results in a 404 then that would seem to rule out the "cache").

It's also possible you have directives elsewhere (in the server config) that might be doing this, after all, `MultiViews` must have been explicitly enabled somewhere - this is not enabled by default.

> Moreover, I want it only for php extension. Because when user types domain.com/robots I don't want robots.txt to be displayed, but 404 page.

In that case, you cannot use `MultiViews` to manage your extensionless URLs. You need to use mod_rewrite and internally rewrite the URL instead to specifically target `.php` files only.

Try the following instead:

```
# Ensure that MultiViews is disabled
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

# Specify the actual file in the ErrorDocument, not simply "/404"
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite extensionless URL to ".php" if it exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

The regex `^([^.]+)$` assumes that your extensionless URLs do not otherwise contain a dot. The only dot occurs before the file extension `.php` - which is omitted in the request. This allows the directive to be more efficient and to avoid checking static resources etc. and to naturally avoid rechecking the request after it has been internally rewritten to append the `.php` extension (when applicable).

However, this may or may not resolve the redirect issue. This may depend on how the redirect is being triggered in the first place.

---

As an added bonus you can also redirect direct requests for `.php` files to *remove* the file extension. This is necessary if you are changing an existing URL structure where the `.php` URL might have been indexed by search engines and/or linked to by external third parties.

To do this you would add the following rule immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive and *before* the internal rewrite (that appends the extension).

```
# Remove the ".php" extension on direct requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The *condition* that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we only check direct requests from the client and not *rewritten* requests by the later directive.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

However, if the earlier "redirect issue" has not already been resolved then this will likely result in a redirect-loop.